# Convert between negative likelihood ratio and a positive likelihood ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm having a lot of trouble converting a positive likelihood ratio into a negative likelihood ratio. Let's say there's an individual who undergoes some sort of medical test. They get the test back and it is negative. In order to interpret this result in the context of post-test probabilities, the physician running the test needs the negative likelihood ratio $LR- = \frac{1- \text{sensitivity}}{\text{specificity}}$.

However, let's say that I am only given the positive likelihood ratio $LR+ = \frac{\text{sensitivity}}{1- \text{specificity}}$, and to consider an example, say it's $5$. How can I get $LR-$ if I only have $LR+$, and no information about the true positive/negative or false positive/negative rates, or prevalence?

Essentially, if $x$ is the sensitivity and $y$ is the specificity, I'm trying to convert
$$5 = \frac{x}{1-y}$$
into
$$\text{something} = \frac{1-x}{y}.$$

Comment: Think about $x = 1/2, y = 9/10$ and $x = 1/3, y = 14/15$.

Comment: @ronno I tried thinking about that, and the "something" (the negative likelihood ratio) I'm trying to find becomes 5/9 and 5/7. It looks like the LR- isn't staying the same just because the LR+ is constant, which means I would need x and y to know what the LR- is? I guess then there isn't a way to find the LR- just from the LR+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thinking about the formulas and ignoring the semantics of sensitivity, specificity and so on, the problem is that $\frac{1-x}{y}$ cannot be determined by only knowing $\frac{x}{1-y}$. For instance, the equation $5 = \frac{x}{1-y}$ is satisfied by both the cases $x = 1/2$, $y = 9/10$ and $x = 1/3$, $y = 14/15$, but the corresponding values of $\frac{1-x}{y}$ are $5/9$ and $5/7$ respectively.

If you additionally know one of $x$ or $y$ then you can solve for the other one and plug into the formula, for example if you know $x$ then
$$5 = \frac{x}{1-y} \implies y = 1 - \frac{x}{5} \implies \frac{1-x}{y} = \frac{5(1 - x)}{5-x}.$$

Comment: Yep this makes sense, I got the same formulas when I was working around with it earlier. Thank you for the help!